# How to cluster and paginate data locations on a map

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, geolocation, search

I have many data points on my map and want to paginate the results into a fixed number of results per page. What I need to figure out now is how to rank or basically decide which location goes to which page. I looked at some of the websites like Kayak and seems like they decided to split the results in a way that given a view point(bbox) the locations on the same page are distributed nicely and are not overlapping so much.

Imagine, you have 40 results and you want to show 20 results per page so you want to come up with an algorithm that divides this into two groups of 20 items and each group is nicely distributed in the bbox.

I might be able to write something greedy myself but just wondering if there is an existing algorithm that I can use.

Here is the sample of the expected behavior:

Page 1 results:
[image]

Page 2 results:
[image]

Comment: The example is not spatially super smart. If it had no financial interest, it could just be a random selection. But it has a commercial interest, so maybe it is more a sort based on your preference (family vs business trip etc), with a touch of diversity (hotel with/without a pool etc). Or maybe it is sorted by their commission %, or alphabetically, or a mix. That to say it may not be a spatial sort at all!